# VBA - turn on auto calculation AFTER Workbook is closed

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel file that automatically disables autocalculation when starting. It's a huge file with lots of rows of data and formulas. 
I usually filter for what I need and then calculate only the filtered data.

So far so good. When closing the Workbook it automatically enables automatic calculation again, so that it's active when working i different workbooks.

I use these Workbook events to do so

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculateManual
Application.CalculateBeforeSave = False

End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic


End Sub
```

The problem is, that as soon as I hit the X button to close the workbook the Workbook_BeforeClose event starts and the whole file starts to calculate. It takes up to five minutes and only after the calculation is finished, I can save and close the workbook.

I would like to have automatic calculation reactivated AFTER the Workbook is closed, so that excel does not calculate the whole Workbook any longer but that autocalculation is enabled again in any other workbook.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: Skip to the second solution. After reading the comments, the below approach will *work* but it is less than ideal. The second approach is more efficient and effective given the task. I am keeping the original solution here solely to keep edits and updates apparent.

### Initial Solution

I think I have a solution for you (and in the process I learned something new).

While `EnableEvents` belongs to the `Application` object, `EnableCalculation` belongs to the worksheet object. This allows us to be very precise in which sheets we want to calculate.

```
Option Explicit
Public AppCalcSetting As Long
Public AppEventSetting As Long

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ' Remember the application events setting
    AppEventSetting = Application.EnableEvents

    ' Turn off Calculation for the specified worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).EnableCalculation = False

    ' Prevent other events from firing
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Turn Application level calculation back to what it was previously set to
    Application.Calculation = AppCalcSetting

    ' Restore EnableEvents
    Application.EnableEvents = AppEventSetting

    ' Turn Calculation ability back on
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).EnableCalculation = True
End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Remembers user preferences for calculation mode.
    AppCalcSetting = Application.Calculation

    ' Turn off Automatic Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End Sub
```

I ran a few tests and I was successfully able to suppress a worksheet from calculating, while still changing the application.calculation mode.

Keep in mind that while `Worksheet.Calculation` mode is set to false the worksheet cannot be calculated, so this option must be restored if the user intends to calculate new values.

### Second Solution

Per A.S.H here's another approach that avoids the application setting entirely (note that this only performs on the first sheet and this would need to be edited accordingly):

```
Public Sub Calculate()

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .EnableCalculation = True
        .Calculate
        .EnableCalculation = False
    End With
End Sub
```

You can bind this to a hotkey or a button. Just make sure you also have this event in the workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).EnableCalculation = False
End Sub
```

I havent tested how this would work on filtered data, but it will solve the calculation problem without needing to worry about any application-level events.

Comment: But again, when setting `xlCalculationManual` in this workbook, the other open workbooks will also stop calculating automatically. Therefore *"having users think their computer is acting weird"* (as per your own remark) seems somewhat unavoidable and due to the very initial design choices in Excel. That's why I *give up* on it.

Comment: I was more concerned about the Calculation mode setting persisting to other workbooks after the problem workbook is closed. This solves that problem. It is possible to go one step further and skip calculation modes entirely (all that would be needed is a 'Calculate' sub).

Comment: @A.S.H In all fairness though, the challenge (and holding me to my own argument) does make for an even better solution. Kudos!

Comment: Yeas, it's better now, +1 for pointing to some way to disable calculation in a specific worksheet or workbook (one can iterate on all worksheets in the WB and apply your method). One should really be very careful when using the application calc setting across workbooks. Better avoid it altogether.

Comment: Note : the Worksheet.EnableCalculation setting does not persist in a saved workbook.  Also toggling EnableCalculation from False to True dirties ALL the formulas on the worksheet so making the next sheet calc a full calc.

Comment: Setting EnableCalculation back to True whilst in automatic mode will trigger a calculation so I think your code should not set it back to True (unless you switch off events) - since it does not persist you don't need to reset it anyway. See http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm for more comments on enablecalculation

Comment: @CharlesWilliams The fact that it dirties all formulas is certainly less than ideal, but for the given circumstances I imagine it is better than the alternative of the sheet calculating without being explicitly requested. Also worth noting is that, given the comments, the initial solution I provided certainly is less than worthwhile. The second solution should be more effective, particularly given your Calculation comment, though it does raise the concern of whether the second solution would calculate twice? I dont know enough about how excel makes calc decisions to know for sure.

Comment: I have implemented a complete general-purpose solution in my FastExcel product, but its quite complex to do. I still think the easiest solution for the OP is the timed reset, but you can probably implement a reasonably straightforward solution to his problem based on your approach. Note that where there are links between worksheets you need to generalize to all sheets.

Comment: @CharlesWilliams The timed reset would be effective for a single user who understands how it works, but it is not effective when working on a team (because the file that contains the calling macro has to be available to them). I agree that the solution should be generalized, and it was only intended as a template of sorts. He will want to substitute his sheets where I have used only a single sheet. Given that I dont know the structure of his file from his post, it is impossible to build a complete and efficient approach that he doesnt need to adjust.

Comment: Wow guys, you are great! Haven't expected such an informative discussion going on. It seems that Brandon's second solution could do the trick if one agreed with having auto calculation always off. 
It seems that there is no easy solution to this, but luckily I discovered that you can actually end the calculation process by hitting ESC. I guess for this case this will do the trick. 
Thanks anyways for your solutions and comments, I learned a lot from them

Answer (score 0):

One somewhat hacky solution could be to run a sub to set calculation back to automatic on a time delay so that it runs after the workbook has finished closing.

Really what is needed is a way to set calculation mode for individual workbooks: see my suggestion on Uservoice

https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304921-excel-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/10601079-workbook-level-calculation

Comment: Problem is that the code to turn calc back on must not be in that same slow workbook, otherwise the workbook will be opened again thanks to the Ontime macro :-). This is not a simple nut to crack if other workbooks may be open at the same time.

Comment: @JKP - True - the sub needs to be in an addin or personal.xls

Comment: @jkpieterse That could be solved by storing the code for the macro within another (readily available) workbook. Not the ideal solution, but the only other approach that I can think of would be to use VBScript, and I doubt anyone wants to go that route for something so simple.

Comment: @Brandon, @ Charles. Of course. But to get a water-tight solution is very hard or perhaps even impossible, given that there is no way to know whether workbook "foo" which happens to be open was saved with calc set to manual or to automatic. So what calc mode needs to be set? As Charles said: we need a workbook-level calc setting to fix this once and for all.

Answer (score 0):

You just use the wrong value, is not **xlAutomatic** it's just **xlCalculationAutomatic**

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
        Application.Calculation = XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic
    End Sub
```